# From where to download pure Android SDK without ADT?

Tags: android, sdk, bundle, adt

I am googling like a mad but I am unable to find out from where I should download basic Android SDK zip (tar.gz).

I was used to download that zip, extract it and that's it. Now all what is offered to me is some weird Android ADT "bundle" which goes with some Eclipse x.y.z I am not totally interested into. I just need *pure* android-sdk with all these binaries for creating emulators and stuff from the command line. I *do not* want any bundled IDE. Right now, what I get in one zip is:

Eclipse + ADT plugin <-- I do not want this at all

Android SDK Tools

Android Platform-tools

The latest Android platform

The latest Android system image for the emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this [site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and click on `Using an existing IDE`. There is the Android SDK.